# how to read the contents of a file in lua without the "io" library?

Tags: lua

how to read the contents of a file without the "io" library in lua using ffi? I would be grateful if you could help me

```
function read(file)
 --code
end
```

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: What about using `dofile()` or `require()`? What exactly are you trying to do? And what have you tried? And what happened? It is much easier to help you debug your code if you show us your code.